# What all changes I need to make when I add new url in web config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a WCF service where I am consuming another asp.net web api endpoint. The url for the web api is :

```
<add key="AccountApiUrl" value="http://localhost:48712/Accounts" />
```

This is the new entry in web config of my WCF service. What all changes I need to make that this new change goes till production. I understand in production Url will be changed?Do I need to make any entry into web.release.config or web.debug.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace localhost with your website domain name like http://www.yourwebserviceurl.com/Accounts

Change your web.config file on production - that should be fine.